# How to configure Eclipse/CDT/C++ formatter to not break line between a function returned type and the function name

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, formatter

I'm using Eclipse/CDT for my C++ projects. I really like the C++ formatter but there is one of its settings that I have not been able to find (Window->Preferences->C/C++->Code Style->Formatter). The formatter always put a line break between a function returned type and the name of the function. For example, it changes the following code:

```
void f()
{
}
```

to:

```
void 
f()
{
}
```

Is there a way to avoid suppress this line break?

NB: I'm using Eclipse Juno SR1 and CDT 8.1.1 on Linux.